# Automatically Refresh JmDNS Services in Activity

Tags: android, listactivity, android-activity, zeroconf, jmdns

I'm trying to automatically refresh JmDNS services in the background.  Nothing is happening when I try:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    try {
        hiNeighborService.unregisterListener(this);
        this.unbindService(this.serviceConnection);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception occur during destroying the app.");
    }

    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    /*new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                refreshServices();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 

    }).start();*/

    ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

    // This schedule a runnable task every 2 minutes
    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        rebindService();
        refreshServices();
      }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onRestart() {
    /*new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                refreshServices();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 

    }).start();*/
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

    // This schedule a runnable task every 2 minutes
    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        rebindService();
        refreshServices();
      }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    /*new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                refreshServices();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 

    }).start();*/

    ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

    // This schedule a runnable task every 2 minutes
    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        rebindService();
        refreshServices();
      }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    super.onResume();
}
```

This is my resfreshServices() method:

```
private void refreshServices() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Refresh available neighbors...");
    final List<Neighbor> activeNeighbors = this.hiNeighborService
            .getActiveNeighbors();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, activeNeighbors.size() + " active neighbors are found!");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "refresh UI...");
            try {

                synchronized (activeNeighborsViewModel) {
                    activeNeighborsViewModel.clear();
                    for (Neighbor neighbor : activeNeighbors) {
                        NeighborViewModel vm = new NeighborViewModel(
                                neighbor);
                        vm.setNeighborUnreadCount(ConnectActivity.this
                                .getUnreadMessageCount(neighbor));
                        if (activeNeighborsViewModel.contains(vm)) {
                            activeNeighborsViewModel.remove(vm);
                        }

                        activeNeighborsViewModel.add(vm);
                    }
                }
                notifyServiceListChanged();

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "refresh completed!");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Normally that gets call when a button is clicked however I would like it to be automatic.  This code doesn't do anything unless I hit the Resfresh button that call resfreshServices().  I attempted to try it with threads but the activity closes and so does the app.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a little comment on your code. Why are you implementing the same code three times in three different methods. I assume that you are programming android (loking at your method names). The method onresume is executed every time the activity is started or resumed. See [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) for more information on this topic.

Ok, then... Did you already check the docs for more information about the [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)?

Now for the jmdns issue. The jmDns library has a build in functionality to update the services. you can listen to new services and take the appropriate action when new services are available. I do not think, that repeated polling of the services is the right approach.

Look [here](http://home.heeere.com/tech-androidjmdns.html) for a little tutorial on using jmdns in android.